# Need a curved vertical line using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a curved vertical line with 5 dots like this -

[image: Desired Output]

On hovering over each dot, text should slide besdide it from left to right, and text should disappear on taking away the mouse.

So far I have only been able to indent and place those 5 dots by means of modifying `margin-left`property for each item in the list. I am not able to get the curved line. How do I achieve that?

Comment: how about an image in the div behind them?

Comment: This could be a good case for canvas. Could you share what you have now in a fiddle?

Comment: @TarynEast: It's difficult to align the dots with the background image all the time. Need to take into account screen re-sizing and various resolutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Background:

`Border-radius` is really great for creating the appearance of curves. The problem is that anything inside an container which is curved using this style ignores said curving. As you pointed out, we need to use margins. However, by keeping everything symmetric, we can keep the `margin-left`s to three sets, one of which doesn't require a class.

### Answer:

We can get away with a very simple structure here:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Text</span></li>
</ul>
```

We have the `ul` as the outer wrapper with the top and bottom horizontal borders. We use a `::before` pseudo-element attached to the wrapper, to create the curved line. Each `li` is the menu entry. The blue circles are created with `::before` pseudo-elements attached to the `li`, and we can achieve the text animation via the `span` inside. We could get away with not having a `span`, but we'd need to declare the actual text content in the CSS, and I think it belongs in the HTML.

The CSS isn't too bad. We curve the `ul::before` and give it the border. We make it larger than `100%` because the curve you show cuts off the top and bottom.

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Code:

```css
ul {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    border-top:solid 2px black;
    border-bottom:solid 2px black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul::before {
    height:133%;
    width:133%;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:solid 2px black;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-18%;
    left:10px;
    content:"";
}
li {
    margin:28px 0;
    color:lightblue;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li::before {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    margin-right:6px;
}
li.right {
    margin-left:30px;
}
li.middle {
    margin-left:6px;
}
li span {
    position:relative;
    left:-100%;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
li:hover span {
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="right"><span>Anecdotes</span></li>
    <li class="middle"><span>Interviews</span></li>
    <li><span>Records</span></li>
    <li class="middle"><span>Recent Stats</span></li>
    <li class="right"><span>Recent Snaps</span></li>
</ul>
```

Success! As mentioned, this might be better using Canvas, or possible SVG. But if you want to stay strictly with HTML & CSS, this should help.

---

### Second Method

Another way we can do this, staying with HTML & CSS, is to use `transform:translate`. I thought this might be easier and more reliable, but it turns out it requires more CSS and more classes. However, I got it working so I'm going to post it here anyway, because despite that it's pretty cool I think.

```css
ul {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    border-top:solid 2px black;
    border-bottom:solid 2px black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul::before {
    height:133%;
    width:133%;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:solid 2px black;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-17.5%;
    left:10px;
    content:"";
}
li {
    margin:0;
    color:lightblue;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-top:-15px;
}
li::before {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    margin-right:6px;
}
li.one {
    transform: translate(60px) rotate(-140deg) translate(208px) rotate(140deg);
}
li.two {
    transform: translate(60px) rotate(-160deg) translate(208px) rotate(160deg);
}
li.three {
    transform: translate(60px) rotate(-180deg) translate(208px) rotate(180deg);
}
li.four {
    transform: translate(60px) rotate(-200deg) translate(208px) rotate(200deg);
}
li.five {
    transform: translate(60px) rotate(-220deg) translate(208px) rotate(220deg)
}
li span {
    position:relative;
    left:-100%;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
li:hover span {
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="one"><span>Anecdotes</span></li>
    <li class="two"><span>Interviews</span></li>
    <li class="three"><span>Records</span></li>
    <li class="four"><span>Recent Stats</span></li>
    <li class="five"><span>Recent Snaps</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much :) With HTML5 canvas, is it possible to implement this with reduced coding? I'm just interested in the canvas version of the code to compare and enhance to get what I have in mind.

Comment: I'm glad i could help. I'm not sure about the canvas. I've never done much with it. I'll look into it today though.

Comment: I've been looking into Canvas and have realized that it's a bit more in depth than I thought. It'll take me more than a day to teach myself Canvas from scratch to try and figure this out. There are a lot of resources online though, if you'd like to dive in yourself.

Comment: Loads of thanks for your help :) Yes, I'm also researching the same through online resources.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can achieve the curve, dots, and text display below. You have to adjust it to suit your need.

```css
#arch {
  border-left: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
#arch-outer {
  /* serves as a blade to cut off overly curved area */
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Cuts off the overly cured area */
}
#arch li {
  font-size: 76px;
  height: 85px;
  color: rgb(153, 217, 234);
}
#arch li:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#arch li:nth-of-type(4) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#arch li:nth-of-type(5) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
#arch li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 76px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: rgb(153, 217, 234);
}
```

```html
<div id="arch-outer">
  <div id="arch">


    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Five</a>
      </li>
      <ul>


  </div>
  <!-- End arch -->
</div>
<!-- End arch outer -->
```

[View on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veohs1os/)

Comment: The text doesn't animate though.

Comment: @AndyM focused on the curve and dots.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 1 blank `<div class="curve"></div>` and display only `left border` of that div as below:

```
.curve{
border-left:2px solid #000;
height:200px;
width:100px;
border-radius:50px; /*see how much you want to curve*/
}
```

OR else

create 1 curve `image` and apply to that background div and with help of `position` float your dot div on it and with `hover effect` show your text.

check here http://jsfiddle.net/Lz97rgyf/2/

Comment: Problem with this is that the inner text won't follow the curve. Border-radius only changes the appearance, but the box is still square.